# Jackson Adding a Custom Serializer for all fields of Type X

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private Integer id;
    private FooB fooA;
    private boolean isB;
    private boolean isC;
    private int age;
    private LocalDate date1;
    private LocalDate date2;
    private LocalDate date3;
    private LocalDate date4;
}
```

I want to serialize everything in this class natively **except** for the `LocalDate` fields. I have a custom serializer for that like so:

```
public class LocalDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate localDate, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        //serialize
    }
}
```

Is there a way to annotate the class `Foo` to say only use the serializer for objects of type `LocalDate` **or** do I have to go annotate each individual field like so:

```
public class Foo {
    private Integer id;
    private FooB fooA;
    private boolean isB;
    private boolean isC;
    private int age;
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate date1;
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate date2;
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate date3;
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate date4;
}
```

My question is, can I consolidate that into a single class level annotation?

Comment: Looks like adding a custom module is the way to go. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/07/01/custom-serializer-jackson/

Comment: @MaxPower that's not the question i'm asking. I've already written a custom serializer. I'm asking about annotations

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution that uses only one annotation in the class. Probably annotating each field is the best you can get.

---

Another way is to configure the `ObjectMapper` programatically:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
module.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
om.registerModule(module);
```

The `addSerializer` method maps all `LocalDate` fields to use the specified serializer. In the example above, I used the built-in `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateSerializer` with a `DateTimeFormatter`, but of course you can replace it with any serializer you want (including your custom one).

If you don't want to (or can't) configure the `ObjectMapper`, then using the annotations on each field seems to be the best solution.